# IoT/WinJS/VS - JavaScript runtime error: Invalid system-wide (SPI_*) parameter

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, raspberry-pi, winjs, iot

I am trying to run my first sample app in WinJS, on a Raspberry Pi 2, and I'm getting a runtime error. The code is really simple, just an AppBar and a couple of AppBarCommand buttons. The program runs just fine when run as Any CPU -> Local Machine. However, when run as ARM -> Remote Machine, it throws the runtime error. Interestingly, using breakpoints, I've found that the offending code is not run at all when using the Local Machine, so no runtime error.

The error occurs when a default tooltip is created for the AppBarCommand. Here is the code:

```
                // Set system attributes if it is in WWA, otherwise, use the default values
            if (!hasInitWinRTSettings && _WinRT.Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UISettings) { // in WWA
                var uiSettings = new _WinRT.Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UISettings();
                mouseHoverTime = _TransitionAnimation._animationTimeAdjustment(uiSettings.mouseHoverTime);
```

The runtime error is:

0x8007059f - JavaScript runtime error: Invalid system-wide (SPI_*) parameter.

The interesting thing is that uiSettings contains this value for some of the settings, including mouseHoverTime, which causes the runtime error above.

Any ideas why the call to _WinRT.Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UISettings should result in some erroneous setting values?

Regards,

Paul